# Firebase error Function CollectionReference.doc()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following project in react connecting with firebase is having the following issues code. Once the enter button is clicked to submit the message it bring back the error from the database.(picture bellow) . I created the collection "rooms" and I am trying to access with  **db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection({ })** line 17 which is bringing back the error from firebase.

what does this error message means?
FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: true

I removed firebase.ps1 file an logged back.
created a new db.collection still the same.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ChatInput.css";
import db from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function ChatInput({ channelName, channelId }) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [{ user }] = useStateValue();


    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (channelId) {
              db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection({
                message: input,
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp,
                user: user.displayName,
                userImage: user.photoURL,
             });
         }

         setInput("");

    };


    return (
        <div className="chatInput">

            <form>
                
                <input
                value={input}
                onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                placeholder={`Message #${channelName?.toLowerCase()}`} />

                    <Button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
                        SEND</Button>

            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

export default ChatInput;
```

**also added the following code and still getting the same issue
[Changes made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LRjN.png) [changes made 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q19s4.png)

[function collectionreference-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Uvm.png)
[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY08U.png)

Answer (score 2):

> what does this error message means? FirebaseError: Function
> CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type
> non-empty string, but it was: true

It means that you need to pass a String as argument of the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method.

You are passing `channelId` to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method and it seems it is a boolean with value `true`. You need to pass a String which represents the ID of the Firestore Document. I guess it is `channelName`, isn't it?

---

In addition, there is another problem in your code: you are passing a JavaScript object to the [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) method.

---

If you want to "submit a message", you need, for example, to call the [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method on the `CollectionReference`.

Something like the following (we don't know the subcollection name you want to use, let's take 'messages'):

```
db.collection("rooms").doc(channelName).collection('messages')
  .add({
       message: input,
       timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp,
       user: user.displayName,
       userImage: user.photoURL,
  });
```

---

I would suggest that you have a look at the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am trying to do and with sub collection 'messages', after adding the missing parameters I still get the same message pointing to the same line. I added the pictures in the question "Changes made" "changes made 2"

Comment: Hi Lucas, did you have the opportunity to look at the update? Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: yes I did but nothing is showing to accept in my end... I upvoted but (is that what you mean?) it will show up only i reach another 14 points...

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ChatMsg.css";
import db from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./stateProvider";

function ChatMsg({ channelName, channelId }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [{ user }] = useStateValue();
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (channelId) {
      db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection('messages').add({
        message: input,
        user: user.displayName,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        userimage:user.photoURL
        
       
      });
            
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="chatInput">
      <form>
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          placeholder={`Message # ${channelName}`}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
          SEND
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ChatMsg;
```